# concatinate two variables in javascript not working object

Tags: javascript

I am trying to access the variable localise.courseEN  but it is returning `undefinedEN`

How can I make it work

```
var localise = {
    courseEN : "English",
}
var learnLang = "EN";
alert( localise.course + learnLang);
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable

Answer (score 2):

```
var localiseEN = {

    courseEN : "English"
};
var learnLang = 'EN';
alert( localiseEN.courseEN + learnLang);
```

Like this?

Comment: it should alert `"EnglishEN"` which is probably not the desired result.